# DDD Объекты-значения (Value objects)

Tags: архитектура, ddd

**Ситуация:**

В системе есть некая сущность, описываемая рядом параметров.

Каждый параметр является композицией из трех составляющих:

- назначение;
- значение;
- единицы измерения.

Если я правильно понимаю подход DDD, то объектом-значением является то, что описывает сущность или другой объект-значение (например, валюта).

В данном случае все три составляющие описывают параметр и должны являться объектами-значениями.

Однако в системе должна быть возможность конструирования дополнительных параметров. Соответственно единицы измерения должны браться из определенного справочника.

**Вопрос:**

Не совсем понимаю: как реализовать данный сценарий при условии того, что единицы измерения должны быть объектом-значением, который по своей сути не допускает наличия ID?

Ведь намного проще было бы использовать параметр, в котором Тип параметра и Единицы измерения были бы представлены только как их ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, можно Measure сделать отдельной сущностью с атрибутами и своим репозитарием

```
Measure
    ID
    Name
```

а в Param ссылатся на Measure по ID

```
Param
    name
    value
    measure_id

SomeEntity
    ID
    params []Params
```

То есть агрегат SomeEntity будет содержать много объектов значений Params и не позволять ссылаться им по ссылке вовне, только по идентификатору на другой агрегат Measure

Comment: Здравствуйте. Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ!
Я долго думал над этим вопросом. В конечном счете понял, что вариант, который Вы предложили - самый оптимальный. Ведь главная задача при разработке модели - снизить сложность).
Есть хорошая ссылка, где автор аналогичного вопроса пришел к такому же выводу (раздел Final Solution):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808481/what-is-a-practical-way-to-model-lookup-tables-in-domain-driven-design-ddd

Таким образом, данные сущности из справочных таблиц я бы назвал "Неизменяемые сущности")

Comment: Это уже к реализации на конкретном ЯП. Потому что агрегат должен извлекаться целиком со всем деревом объектов, которые в него входят, из хранилища. Поэтому составляющие его объекты не должны иметь ссылок вовне агрегата, им разрешено ссылатся на другие агрегаты только по идентификатору, например для Param тип атрибута measure_id INT32, а не *Measure

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, я понял) Просто невнимательно читал Ваш ответ)

Comment: Порекомендую книгу Scott Millett, Nick Tune, Patterns, Principles, and Practices of Domain-Driven Design есть в переводе на русский. Там очень хорошие примеры и объяснения. Ну и Эванса тоже читать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за книги)
Есть по DDD одна великолепная книга за авторством Вон Вернона "Реализация методов предметно-ориентированного проектирования"
Там все очень подробно расписано)

Comment: Я ее всю читал в переводе, местами ужасно, а вот перевод книги Scott Millett отличный, очень четкое изложение с хорошими примерами.

Comment: Обязательно с ней ознакомлюсь) Мне нравится подход DDD)

Comment: Олег, огромное Вам спасибо за рекомендацию почитать книгу Скотта Миллета. Книга просто великолепна! Написана простым и понятным языком. Все четко расставляет на свои места)